# arm gcc const string array not placed in rodata

Tags: c, gcc, arm

On ARM-GCC in C
when defining a const string array and accessing it directly the strings are correctly placed in the .rodata section.

If I however have a struct with a pointer to the string array placed in .data section and uses ram. How can I put myStrings into a read only section and save ram?

```
const char * myStrings[] = {"String1", "String2"};   //.rodata
const char * myStrings2[] = {"String3", "String4"};  //.data

typdef struct {
const char ** strings;
int a;
} mystruct_t;

const mystruct_t mystruct = {myStrings2,2};

void main()
{
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",myStrings[i]); 
        printf("%s",mystruct.strings[i]);
    }
}
```

edit: provided minimal code.

Comment: Is it the string literals themselves or the array of pointers that's being placed in .data?

Comment: This is no valid C code. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]! Note that a pointer is not an array.

Comment: ...and you're missing an identifier in `const mystruct_t = {myStrings,2};`

Comment: @Dmitri you are correct! based on the size, it is in face the pointers that are stored in data (4byte per string). Still this should not be necessary ? Can I avoid this?

Comment: @Olaf will change the question according to guidelines

Comment: Try `char const * const myStrings[] = ...`.  The first `const` applies to the `char` (like in your original line), and the second to the pointers in the array.

Comment: @Dmitri this works, thank you

Comment: I wonder why you think that your data being allocated in `.rodata` saves you RAM. The contents of `.rodata` is loaded into physical RAM just as much as `.data` is. If anything, you may be able to save a COW-page in case you're modifying the data and running several instances of your program, but that seems like a fairly slight thing to worry about.

Comment: according to my linker script, rodata is placed in the text section (in rom)

Comment: Oh, is this for an embedded project? I assumed it was going to run under Linux.

Comment: Don't asnwer your question in the question itself! Remove the answer-part and provide an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Dmitri pointed out, only the pointers to the strings are stored in ram. This can be avoided by declaring them constant as well

```
const char * const myStrings2[] = {"String3", "String4"};

typdef struct {
    const char * const * strings;
    int a;
} mystruct_t;
```